# Java GUI image size

Tags: java, image, layout-manager, java-2d

So I have an assignment where I need to create a catalog.
The catalog needs to have a list, an image and a description.
My entire code works, so I have no issue with the coding as such.

I do have an issue with the image size.
How do I take care of images on a java gui program to make them all into one size when it is running.
Please let me know :D

Answer (score 1):

When you read in an image, create a new BufferedImage that is the exact size that you desire, get it's Graphics object via `getGraphics()`, draw the original image into the new image using `Graphics#drawImage(Image img, int x, int y, int width, int height, ImageObserver observer)` where x and y are 0 and width and height are from the dimensions of the new image, `dispose()` of the Graphics object, and then display the new Image as an ImageIcon in a JLabel. Make sure though that the original image is the same size or larger than the new one, else your images will look gawd-awful.

For example, and note that this code may not be exactly correct since I don't have my IDE up:

```
BufferedImage originalImage = ImageIO.read(something); // read in original image

// create new empty image of desired size
BufferedImage newImage = new BufferedImage(desiredWidth, desiredHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
Graphics g = newImage.getGraphics();  // get its graphics object

// draw old image into new image
g.drawImage(originalImage, 0, 0, desiredWidth, desiredHeight, null);
g.dispose();  // get rid of Graphics object

// create ImageIcon and put in JLabel to display
Icon newIcon = new ImageIcon(newImage);
myJLabel.setIcon(newIcon);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would propably create a JPanel to draw on one Image, and then work with the method:

```
myPanel.setSize(new Dimension(x,y))
```

or

```
myPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension....)
```

Comment: How will this change the size of a displayed image? All it will do is crop the image if the size you set is smaller than the image, or show the image plus a grey border if it's larger.

Comment: Yea, the question is quite unspecific. This will crop the image, but i thought thats what has been asked, if you have different proportions of images. if it is just a matter of scaling/resizing your image your answer is the one to go with.

Answer (score 0):

There is a method (`image = imgobj.getScaledInstance(width, height, hints)`) in awt.Image class which provides re-sizing capabilities very nicely, I always use this to re-size my images when I need. Please see [here](http://www.javadocexamples.com/java/awt/Image/getScaledInstance%28int%20width,int%20height,int%20hints%29.html) some examples :-), I hope it will work for you, it is the most convenient way to scale images I have ever seen. create a method pass the image to the method and size of the image you want and return the image back in return to reuse the code ;)